# Drupal 8 - Creating a simple module, using .settings file

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I just want to accomplish one thing, set a var in a .settings file and use this var on .module file.

Sounds simple, but I just can't figure out how do this.

What I've done so far:

-Files:
modulename 
_|-> modulename.info.yml
_|-> modulename.module
_|-> config
____|-> modulename.settings.yml

-Content of modulename.settings.yml:

```
some_string: 'A string'
some_int: 42
some_bool: true
```

-Content of modulename.info.yml:

```
name: modulename
type: module
description: 'Some description.'
package: Custom
version: 8.x-1.0
core: 8.x
configure: config/modulename
hidden: false
```

-Content of modulename.module:

```
<?php
...[omitted]...
print_r('Printed');
print_r(get_class(\Drupal::config('modulename.settings'))); //Prints 'Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig'
print_r(\Drupal::config('modulename.settings')->get('some_string')); //nothing
print_r(\Drupal::config('modulename.settings')->get('modulename.some_string')); //nothing
print_r(\Drupal::config('modulename')->get('some_string')); //nothing
print_r(\Drupal::config('config.modulename')->get('some_string')); //nothing
print_r(\Drupal::config('config.modulename.settings')->get('some_string')); //nothing
```

I'm able to install this module and print some info on page, but i can't access any var.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should place your settings.yml file inside the modulename/config/install folder (and probably you have to uninstall and install the module again).

Also one side note about the 'configure: config/modulename' in your info file: I think that should point to a route name which represents the page which is used to configure the module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it, settings.yml was in a wrong folder, just moved to 'install' folder and now everything is fine. In this case, point a route wasn't necessary. To get my var I used `print_r(\Drupal::config('modulename.settings')->get('some_string'));`. sry for late response, working a lot ;).